# Python Tkinter - Set Entry grid width 100%

Tags: python, tkinter

When i create `button + entry + button` in grid, `entry` was centered but not completely fill the column. How i can fill the column via `Entry`?

[image]

```
# Python 3.4.1

import io
import requests
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def get_image():
    im = requests.get('http://lorempixel.com/' + str(random.randint(300, 400)) + '/' + str(random.randint(70, 120)) + '/')
    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(im.content))


class ImageSelect(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        master.title('Image manager')
        master.iconify = False
        master.deiconify = False
        master.grab_set = True

        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(get_image())
        self.image = tk.Label(image=image)
        self.image.image = image
        self.image.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)


        self.reload = tk.Button(text='Reload').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.path = tk.Entry().grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='we')
        self.submit = tk.Button(text='Submit').grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='e')

root = tk.Tk()
app = ImageSelect(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using `grid()` you can use `grid_columnconfigure()` on parent of `Entry`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Entry(root).grid(sticky='we')
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Using `pack()` you could use `fill='x'`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Entry(root).pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: using:

```
self.path = tk.Entry().grid()
```

you assign result of `grid()` to `self.path` but `grid()` always return `None`.

If you need `self.path` then do:

```
self.path = tk.Entry()
self.path.grid()
```

If you don't need `self.path` then you could do:

```
tk.Entry().path.grid()
```

Comment: I set `master.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)` and it work. Thanks.

Comment: How can I add paddin to the box? Entry and Button are glued to the corners

Comment: @Codador the same pad in both sides `.grid(..., padx=10)` or dirfferent pad on left and right `.grid(..., padx=(10, 5) )` . The same with `pady` See effbot.org: [Grid](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) BTW: you can also try to remove `sticky='we'` if you don't want to stick/glue to corners/sides.

Answer (score 4):

An `Entry` widget's width is defined by the `width` property.  It is measured in # of characters.  As far as I know there is no native way to make the `Entry` automatically resize to fit a space.  You can set the width like this (the default is 20):

```
self.path = tk.Entry(width=28).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='we')
```

If you really want the `Entry` to automatically grow or shrink, you could bind an event to the window resizing that recalculates and and resets the necessary width of the `Entry`, but it'll be kinda ugly.

Comment: Hmmm... I get this error `_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-width": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
`

Comment: It should be rather `Entry(width=28)`