# Python tkinter geometry management about grid

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry, grid

to make it simple, I ask a simple question,

I want to make 4 buttons, each (full-fill) stays at one corner of the frame container or tkinter window:

```
button_1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Button 1")
button_2 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Button 2")
button_3 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Button 3")
button_4 = tkinter.Button(window, text="Button 4")
button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_4.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

However, they are all tiny buttons that stay together at only the top-left corner of the window, they are not full-filling the entire window as supposed.

Comment: I think this question has been answered. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188810/how-to-make-tkinter-button-widget-take-up-full-width-of-grid

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335

Comment: Alright thanks, I used the grid_columnconfigure and grid_rowconfigure to do that. I only know the sticky keyword when I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `btn.place` to place button based on coordinate system if you dont want to use grid system.Please check the snippet

[image: Button Corner]

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
window = Tk()                 
window.geometry('160x130')             
button1 = Button(window, text="Button 1")
button1.place(x=0,y=0)
button2 = Button(window, text="Button 2")
button2.place(x=100,y=0)
button3 = Button(window, text="Button 3")
button3.place(x=0,y=100)
button4 = Button(window, text="Button 4")
button4.place(x=100,y=100)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Place and resize seems to do the job, but what I long for is your grid_columnconfigure and grid_rowconfigure, thank you!